# Get A Response From A Result (CURL)

Tags: python-3.x, curl

I'm noobie/beginner at Python

I was creating this script

I tried to curl a URL and got a response(A)
now I want to get the response(B) from that response A

```
result = os.popen("curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SirdLay/test/main/test.txt").read()
index = os.popen("curl [what to be used here?]")
```

Comment: As far as I understood you want to use response as a request for other call. Right?

Comment: yes exactly and also I want to paste that response to a file _final.txt_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
response1 = os.popen("curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SirdLay/test/main/test.txt").read()
url = response1[<key>] 
# key is some key in the response1.
# You can print the response1 to see the object.
# For your particular case you dont need a key.
# so you can use
url =  response1
response2 =  os.popen("curl " + url).read()
```

Comment: It works 80%  , but the second request was not successful #/bin/sh: 1: curlhttps://xx.xx/xx.x

Comment: have you added SPACE after curl? Eg: curl url. Notice a space between curl and url.

Comment: thanks a lot that works well , If you dont mind could you explain me how to save/write the response2 to a file

Comment: https://www.pythontutorial.net/python-basics/python-write-text-file/#:~:text=To%20write%20to%20a%20text%20file%20in%20Python%2C,close%20the%20file%20using%20the%20close%20%28%29%20method. This may help.